# Is there any way to fetch last three alphabets between two slashes from a string using regular expression

Tags: regex

From the string

```
t/123test/abc/qwe/jul/374634
```

I need to fetch **test** and store it in a variable.

Need to fetch the strings between slashes and store it in different variables.

Have tried using `^\.t\/.*[A-Z]{3}.*\/\w{3}` but its not getting populated correctly.

Could you please advise on the same.

Comment: Variables are used in programming languages, what is yours? Moreover, why `[A-Z]` if your string has no uppercase letters? What is your pattern supposed to match?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake .. i meant [a-z]. And i need to fetch different segments from a LIANATA code. Need to make an entry in a decoder file of my java program.

Comment: What is a "different segment"? Why do you match a `.` in the pattern while the string starts with `t/`? Try `^t/\d*([a-zA-Z]+)`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wdDKOs/1).

Comment: Yes thank you. Its working. Am able to fetch test alone. And by different segments i meant, the set of strings between each slash. ie; i need to split everything between the slashes as well as if there is alphanumeric string i need to split digits from letters. Could you please tell if the above mentioned expression will work in alphanumeric case also. Instead of 123test if it is 123gheutest how can i fetch test alone.

Comment: @SukanyaS; if the solution helps; please consider accepting it by clicking on the gray tick below the answer and please do consider upvoting the answer too. It'll the future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
^t/\d*([a-zA-Z]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wdDKOs/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Et%2F%5Cd*(%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B)):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `t/` - `t/` substring
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `([a-zA-Z]+)` - Group 1: any one or more ASCII letters.